# How to convert DateTime into text and concate with text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to convert DateTime to text and concate with text.

```
declare @AssignDate datetime 
set @AssignDate =getdate()
select 'Date: ' + convert(char(16),@AssignDate)
```

But my output is coming like: Date: Oct  9 2012  3:0,

My output should be "Date: 09/10/2012 15:30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @AssignDate datetime = getdate()
select 'Date: ' + convert(char(10),@AssignDate,103) + ' '
                + convert(char(5),@AssignDate,108)
```

There isn't a single [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) format that will work, but you can do it in two parts.